# Dialogflow Intent not matched on clicking from Google Assistant's List View Key, but works when written in Plain Text

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I have a certain Intent set-up on Google Dialogflow which matches employee leave-status by a very specific single-word keyword. For example, if the user types "Submitted", it shows that the description stating leave has been in submitted status.

[image]

However, when the exact same keyword is selected from a List View of Google Assistant, dialogflow is not able to match the intent.

[image]

[image]

How is it possible that the same keyword does not match Intent when clicked from a List View, but the same query works in Plain Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a list item(or carousel card) is tapped, it generates an event which will hit your webhook, unlike the simple text message.

**1st way (if your webhook handling the response)**

So you need to handle it in your code.

Generally, it should have `intent` as `actions_intent_OPTION`. from there you need to segregate it.

**2nd way (if your code is not handling the response)**

In this way, your intent must be able to handle `actions_intent_OPTION` event generated by the list(or carousel).

for that, your intent need to add the event as shown in below image (Basically it tells the dialogflow that whenever the `actions_intent_OPTION` events triggered, this intent it capable to handle it, but currently in your case no intent matches the description and it's going to Default Fallback Intent)
[image]

So whenever the list item tapped it can handle the flow.

For more refer [this documentation.](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#list)

Comment: That makes sense. I am however new to Dialogflow, so I have setup the response in the dialogflow front-end without any code, trying to avoid handling responses in code for this being a simple FAQ bot. I don't suppose there is a way to do it?

Comment: Yes I did, but it won't change publicly displayed score because of my reputation.

Comment: Cool, glad to help you!  :)